# Conflict fadeslideshow.js and Jquery to display DIV in center

Tags: jquery, conflict

I am using  script (Given below)  to center the DIV and it is working fine.

```
 <script language="javascript">
    $(document).ready(function(){
       jQuery.fn.center = function () {
      this.css("position","absolute");
      this.css("top", ( $(window).height() - this.height() ) / 2+$(window).scrollTop() + "px");
      this.css("left", ( $(window).width() - this.width() ) / 2+$(window).scrollLeft() + "px");
      return this;
      }
      $("#loading").center();
    });
    </script>
```

refer link  http://webvikas.net.in/savarkar/divincenter1.html
The Loading div is displayed in center

However when I am using fadeslideshow.js in this page

refer http://webvikas.net.in/savarkar/divincenter.html
The Loading div is not displayed in center

How to resolve this ?
 Please help

Script used to center the div

Comment: For starters, don't load jQuery twice.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are loading jQuery twice, but I'm not sure if that's the real problem. Give this a try.

```
$(document).ready(function($){
    $.fn.center = function () {
        this.css("position","absolute");
        this.css("top", ( $(window).height() - this.height() ) / 2+$(window).scrollTop() + "px");
        this.css("left", ( $(window).width() - this.width() ) / 2+$(window).scrollLeft() + "px");
        return this;
    }
    $("#loading").center();
});
```

The problem is that fadeslideshow.js is calling $.noConflict, which is only working on the second version of jQuery. The above will keep everything in the same scope.

Comment: GREAT .. the problem is solved.. Appreciate this LIke to know more on this I believe      $(document).ready(function($){
    $.fn.center = function () {  makes it !!..  what is the difference  .. i mean i will be happy if you can elaborate ... TRUE THE ISSUE IS RESOLVED

Comment: Tried  $(".centerdiv").center(); I could apply this to all DIV having class centerdiv ...really nice and perfect